# PHP Prepared Statements - Not Working - INSERT

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'd like your help in this case. I'm new to prepared statements and trying to insert some information in the database, but I just can't and I can't figure out what's wrong. I already tried to output all the variables I need I'm sure they have the correct values, so, I need your help!

My Function to insert into database.

```
function RegUser($mysqli, $fname, $lname, $username, $password, $email, $seccode){
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO utilizadores (fname, lname, username, password, email, membership, userlevel, active, actcode, maxapps, maxlic, securitycode, uhash) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")){
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssiiisiiis", $pnome, $unome, $user, $pass, $mail, $membro, $level, $ativo, $codigo, $maxapps, $maxlic, $scode, $hash);

            // Dados obtidos do formulario
            $pnome = $fname;
            $unome = $lname;
            $user = $username;
            $pass = $password;
            $mail = $email;
            $scode = $seccode;

            // dados obtidos de função
            $membro = defMember($mysqli);
            $level = defUserlevel($mysqli);
            if(ReqAct($mysqli) == "1"){
                $activo = "0";
            }else{
                $activo = "1";
            }

            $maxapps = GetMaxApps($mysqli, $membro);
            $maxlic = GetMaxLics($mysqli, $membro);

            $codigo = generate_actcode();
            $hash = uHash();

            if($stmt->execute()){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
    }
}
```

My Validation Code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['regbutton'])){
        // verifica se os campos estão preenchidos
        if(empty($_POST['fname'])){
            $errors [] = 'PNOME';
        }
        if(empty($_POST['lname'])){
            $errors [] = 'Preencher UNOME';
        }
        if(empty($_POST['byear'])){
            $errors [] = 'BYEAR';
        }
        if(empty($_POST['username'])){
            $errors [] = 'USERNAME';
        }
        if(empty($_POST['pass'])){
            $errors [] = 'PASS';
        }
        if(empty($_POST['confpass'])){
            $errors [] = 'CONF PASS';
        }
        if(empty($_POST['email'])){
            $errors [] = 'EMAIL';
        }
        if(empty($_POST['confemail'])){
            $errors [] = 'CONFEMAIL';
        }
        if(empty($_POST['cap'])){
            $errors [] = 'CAP';
        }
        if(!isset($_POST['terms'])){
            $errors [] = 'TERMS';
        }
        if((!empty($_POST['fname'])) AND (!empty($_POST['lname'])) AND (!empty($_POST['byear'])) AND (!empty($_POST['username'])) AND (!empty($_POST['pass'])) AND (!empty($_POST['confpass'])) AND (!empty($_POST['email'])) AND (!empty($_POST['confemail'])) AND (!empty($_POST['cap'])) AND (isset($_POST['terms']))){
            $ok = false;
            $fname = validar($link, $_POST['fname']);
            $lname = validar($link, $_POST['lname']);
            $byear = validar($link, $_POST['byear']);
            $username = validar($link, $_POST['username']);
            $pass = validar($link, $_POST['pass']);
            $pass = md5($pass);
            $confpass = validar($link, $_POST['confpass']);
            $confpass = md5($confpass);
            $email = validar($link, $_POST['email']);
            $confemail = validar($link, $_POST['confemail']);
            $cap = validar($link, $_POST['cap']);
            if($cap != $_SESSION['CAPTCHA_CODE']){
                $errors [] = 'Captcha Inválido';
            }
            if($pass != $confpass){
                $errors [] = 'Passwords não conferem';
            }
            if($email != $confemail){
                $errors [] = 'Emails não conferem';
            }
            if(strlen($byear) != "4"){
                $errors [] = 'Ano de Nascimento tem de ter 4 digitos';
            }
            if(strlen($username) < "3" OR strlen($username) > "16"){
                $errors [] = 'User deve ter entre 3 a 16 caracteres';
            }
            if(strlen($pass) < "8" OR strlen($pass) > "32" OR strlen($confpass) < "8" OR strlen($confpass) > "32"){
                $errors [] = 'passwords entre 8 e 32';
            }
            if(RegCheckUser($link, $username) == true){
                $errors [] = 'Username already at use';
            }
            if(RegCheckEmail($link, $email) == true){
                $errors [] = 'Email already in use';
            }
            if(empty($errors)){
                if(RegUser($link, $fname, $lname, $username, $pass, $email, $byear) == true){
                    $ok = true;
                }else{
                    $errors [] = 'Error while creating account';
                }
        }

    }
    if($ok == True){ ?>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <!-- Danger Alert -->
                                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3 class="push"><?php echo $lang['LOGIN_ERROROX']; ?></h3>
            <ul>

    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <!-- END Danger Alert -->
                                </div>
    <?php
    }                       
    if(!empty($errors)){
    ?>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <!-- Danger Alert -->
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h3 class="push"><?php echo $lang['LOGIN_ERROROX']; ?></h3>
            <ul>
            <?php
    foreach ($errors as $value){
        echo "<li align='left'>".$value."</li>";
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <!-- END Danger Alert -->
                                </div>
    <?php
    }
    }

    ?>
```

Can someone help me in this case? I just can't figure out why it turns everytime in the same error ( the code printed is this one just the info inside the $error [] : )

```
    if(empty($errors)){
        if(RegUser($link, $fname, $lname, $username, $pass, $email, $byear) == true){
            $ok = true;
        }else{
            $errors [] = 'Error while creating account';
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the SQL error that is returned if any. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: You can put it inside a `try catch` block and throw the actual `Exception`

Comment: Actually, included the error message you currently are getting as well.